# How to paginate firebase from the last items to the first?

Tags: android, firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get firebase pagination working but I want the newest items first and then the ones slightly older, I tried to work with this but cannot seem to get new values, keeps passing the same ones...I am passing the String Id to endAt which is the path Projects > projectId > moreinfo

```
mDatabase.child("projects").orderByChild("viewCount").limitToLast(25).endAt(offSet.get("first")).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

I tried switching it to startAt and I do not even get results... any ideas?

Comment: hey man were you able to achieve this using firebase?

Comment: Yes see my answer below, that is how I solved it, might require some db restructuring

Comment: Hi Lion, I'm trying to do the pagination, but Firebase always give me the same result. I've open a thead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997375/firebase-android-pagination-load-always-same-items) if you can help me. If not, can you put the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset had to be the same key used for orderByChild - that is why it did not work, so changed this `endAt(offSet.get("first"))` value of the HashMap used to viewCount

Comment: Can you post the code, please? I think that I have the same problem than you

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

While setting the values for projects you have to set one more additional property as timeStump.

```
projects.setTimeStump(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

then you can query like this

```
Query query=myRef.orderByChild("timeStump").limitToLast(50);
```

**Solution 2**

While setting projects you can set .priority variable of firebase as

```
item.setWithPriority(yourObject, 0 - Date.now());
```

and query it like

```
Query query=myRef.child('projects').startAt().limit(20);
```

Comment: I am currently ordering it by something else that is an integer called viewCount, so I need it in order of view count but I want the highest views to show first... and I am trying to use an offset to paginate what you did in solution 1 is not pagination but just grabing the last 50 which I have done already...

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html#between