# How to Implement Paginate a query on android Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

On working around to learn firebase firestore for an example from GitHub [friendly eat app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/firestore)

**I thought to implement pagination to limiting nodes for 10**

> private static final int LIMIT = 10;

in the firestore example app the mAdapter loads data/nodes as below

```
mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    // Get ${LIMIT} restaurants
    mQuery = mFirestore.collection("restaurants")
            .orderBy("avgRating", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(LIMIT);

    // RecyclerView
    mAdapter = new RestaurantAdapter(mQuery, this) {
        @Override
        protected void onDataChanged() {
            // Show/hide content if the query returns empty.
            if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                mRestaurantsRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mRestaurantsRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            // Show a snackbar on errors
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    mRestaurantsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRestaurantsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Filter Dialog
    mFilterDialog = new FilterDialogFragment();
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Start sign in if necessary
    if (shouldStartSignIn()) {
        startSignIn();
        return;
    }

    // Apply filters
    onFilter(mViewModel.getFilters());

    // Start listening for Firestore updates
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

on firestore docs says about to paginate

```
// Construct query for first 25 cities, ordered by population
    Query first = db.collection("cities")
            .orderBy("population")
            .limit(25);

    first.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                    // ...

                    // Get the last visible document
                    DocumentSnapshot lastVisible = 
                    documentSnapshots.getDocuments()
                            .get(documentSnapshots.size() -1);

                    // Construct a new query starting at this document,
                    // get the next 25 cities.
                    Query next = db.collection("cities")
                            .orderBy("population")
                            .startAfter(lastVisible)
                            .limit(25);

                    // Use the query for pagination
                    // ...
                }
            });
```

combining those above codes how should I implement paginate to load more than 10
nodes to load when I scroll to the bottom of the recycler view

> // Use the query for pagination
>
> // ...

**Update:** I am working based on firestore doc about [Paginate query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?authuser=0) and taking look at a [possible duplicate of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711220) I did not get it to done working

Thank you

Comment: This question had been duped incorrectly in the past, but it is now duped correctly.

Comment: I think you might be interested in this article, [How to paginate Firestore using Paging 3 on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df).

Answer (score 0):

**Here I found solution around but not better one, if is there any better way please post**

by saving RecyclerView state before loading more nodes and reloading RecyclerView state after increasing the limit

```
private static final int LIMIT = 10;
```

Changed to

```
private int LIMIT = 10;
```

when recyclerView is scrolled to the bottom

```
mRestaurantsRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            final int mLastVisibleItemPosition = mManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            if ( mLastVisibleItemPosition == (LIMIT-1)) {
                LIMIT = LIMIT*2;
                showSpotDialog();

                // save RecyclerView state
                mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
                Parcelable listState = mRestaurantsRecycler.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
                mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE, listState);

                loadMore(query);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        // restore RecyclerView state
                        if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
                            Parcelable listState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE);
                            mRestaurantsRecycler.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
                        }

                        hideSpotDialog();
                    }

                }, 500);

            }
        }
    });
```

it looks very unusual when nodes are loaded after the limit, but no way for now...
and yes I am looking for loading more nodes without flaws

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the [FirestoreAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/fireeats/adapter/FirestoreAdapter.java) as followed:

1. Keep track DocumentSnapshots identifier.

```java
private Set<String> mIdentifier = new HashSet<>();
```

2. Add a new public method for pagination, as i expect the rest of the query to remain the same, the given query does not need to be changed

```java
/**
 * Extends the query to load even more data rows. This method will do nothing if the query has
 * not yet been set.
 * @param limit the new limit
 */
public void paginate(long limit) {
    if (mQuery != null) {
        if (mRegistration != null) {
            mRegistration.remove();
            mRegistration = null;
        }
        // Expect the query to stay the same, only the limit will change
        mQuery = mQuery.limit(limit);
        startListening();
    }
}
```

3. Clear the identifier in the `setQuery(Query)` method by calling `mIdentifier.clear()`
4. Adopt the `onDocumentAdded(DocumentChange)` and the `onDocumentRemoved(DocumentChange)` as followed

```java
protected void onDocumentAdded(DocumentChange change) {
    if (!mIdentifier.contains(change.getDocument().getId())) {
        mSnapshots.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument());
        mIdentifier.add(change.getDocument().getId());
        notifyItemInserted(change.getNewIndex());
    }
}
protected void onDocumentRemoved(DocumentChange change) {
    mSnapshots.remove(change.getOldIndex());
    mIdentifier.remove(change.getDocument().getId());
    notifyItemRemoved(change.getOldIndex());
}
```

5. For the onScrolling listener i stick to this guide: [Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews and RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView)

Comment: Thank you...  Looks good but I need time interpret myself and to implement, Definitely will try this one

Comment: Hello @Peter A, I am using firebase firestore UI and tried above code this line below  `getSnapshots().add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getNewIndex());`  showing error   **_Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot', required: 'com.domain.appname.model'_**