# Android Firebase Firestore real time update with pagination

Tags: java, android, firebase, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how can I paginate with the new FirebaseFirestore database, when I use real time updates with the `addSnapshotListener`.

The problem I am having is that I can not update the `limit()` once I set the query, so it remains with the same limit, and I am not able to load more data.

This is what I currently have:

```
private Query query = db.collection("groups").orderBy("id", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(15);
```

Those are the query parameters, and I have a `ListenerRegistration` to remove the database listener (I know it can be also doing passing the activity to the `addSnapshotListener` method).

This is the code to fetch the data:

```
registration = query.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        mGroupArrayList.clear();

        if (e != null) {
            Log.w("MAINACTY", "listen:error", e);
            return;
        }

        for (DocumentSnapshot dc : documentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
            // Get the last visible document
            lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments()
                    .get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1);

            mGroupArrayList.add(dc.toObject(Group.class));
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

As is said, the problem is that I can not update the limit I first set on the query, and if I try to do a new query, the old information disappears when an edit is made on the information or when I leave the activity.

In the documentation there is only an example with the `get()` method to paginate, but with that method there is not real time updates.

Comment: May be this will be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711220/firebase-android-pagination

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that is not the new firestore database.