# How to increase limit of "limitToFirst" in Firebase query?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hello guys i fetched data from firebase in recyclerview. For better understanding my question please visit my previous question.
[How do i add the show more functionality to getting firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564573/how-do-i-add-the-show-more-functionality-to-getting-firebase-database)

This is my previous question. For this i found some logic(it might be wrong).
If i set query ,

```
Query sortPost=PostRef.orderByChild("count").limitToFirst(firstTenPost);
```

and i set the Scrolllistner to detect scroll reach at bottom

```
postList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);firstTwoPost=2;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Last", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//So here i want to add +10 items with show more in recyclerview
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you won't need to increase the limit of limitOfFirst().

You should have to try with startAt() method.
Refer below code for better understanding.

On first load:

Code should be,

```
Query sortPost=PostRef.orderByChild("count").limitToFirst(firstTenPost);
```

and on response of this query, find the last key from child records using iterators.

You can get last key from reponse snapshot using below loop,

```
for(DataSnapshot childSnap : dataSnapshot.getChindren()){
   lastKey = childSnap.getKey();
}
```

And On load more use below query,

```
String lastKey = "Last Fetched Key From Earlier Response";
Query sortPost=PostRef.orderByChild("count").startAt(lastKey).limitToFirst(firstTenPost);
```

And on response of this query, update ***lastKey*** variable with last obtains record-key.

**Note: On loadmore response you should have to skip the first value every time to avoid duplicattion of object.**

Comment: how i find lastkey in onbindviewholder and How i come out with lastkey from onbindviewholder

Comment: for(DataSnapshot childSnap : dataSnapshot.getChindren()){
   lastKey = childSnap.getKey();
}

I cant use this loop until i used valueevenelistner.
Please see code i never used listner to get the value

Comment: I think your startAt() call here is slightly off. You should be passing two arguments (the value for orderByChild AND then the lastKey)

Comment: @Kato which two arguments ?

Comment: The value for the orderByChild and the lastKey. [reference doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#endAt(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I am not using Listner and Arraylist, but i used a FirebaseRecyclerOption , so how can i find lastKey from firebase