# How to descending order in Firebase realtime with pagination?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im making query and trying to make an order by rating field. This is paginated list so im making partially queries.

But my query is not sorted.

```
   private void callRealOnlineUsersList(int page, String neededGender) {
    DatabaseReference mReference = realtimeReference.child("OnlineUsers/" + neededGender);
    Query query = mReference.limitToLast(page * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
    query.orderByChild("rating");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<OnlineUser> userList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                OnlineUser user = postSnapshot.getValue(OnlineUser.class);
                userList.add(new OnlineUser(user.getUid(), user.getName(), user.getImage(), user.getGender(), user.getCountry(), user.getRating()));
            }
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ListEvent(userList));
        }
```

Logs are

```
 D/testList: rating 2
            D/testList: rating 1
            D/testList: rating 25
            D/testList: rating 3
            D/testList: rating 1
            D/testList: rating 4
            D/testList: rating 1
            D/testList: rating 10
            D/testList: rating 2
            D/testList: rating 1
            D/testList: rating 25
```

Datasnapshot
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Data Desc Sorting in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android)

Comment: @robsiemb why my code not working even with ascending order?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see your problem (but you still can't sort by descending values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you've combined 3 questions into 1:

- Why isn't my code sorting *at all*?
- Why can't I sort in descending order?
- Given a query that works, how should I do pagination with Firebase RTDB on Android?

Good news, the later 2 of these have good existing answers on StackOverflow!

First, the way you're using `Query` here:

```java
Query query = mReference.limitToLast(page * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
query.orderByChild("rating");
```

isn't correct (and this is why you aren't getting sorted results *at all*).

Instead try this:

```
Query query = mReference
                 .limitToLast(page * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD)
                 .orderByChild("rating");
```

If you just call `orderByChild`, it returns a query that does that, but in your code you are ignoring the result.

To help make it clearer what is happening, you could also do this and it would work (but your current code doesn't save the result of the `orderByChild` call:

```java
Query query = mReference.limitToLast(page * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);
query = query.orderByChild("rating");
```

Second, [you can't sort by descending order in Firebase RTDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34156996/3399890), so you should look at that question for possible solutions.

Finally, your current code will always be returning larger and larger numbers of results as `page` increases -- you don't always get just `TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD` results.  A more complete SO question about pagination [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37711220/3399890).

Comment: what do you mean ignoring? could you please explain?

Comment: You're not using the return value.  It just gets thrown away, and then you pass a query which only has a limit to the `ValueEventListener`.

Comment: could you please edited code how it suppose to be to understand my issue?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking.  I've added your incorrect code to my answer, that code needs to be replaced with one of the two options I provided.

Comment: I have tried your code but now it takes only first ten items and not getting rest of them

Comment: I presume `TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD` is 10?  That's exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: yes i need to make 10 + next 10 + next 10... but for some reason it is not working

Comment: There's also good existing questions for pagination, rather than writing duplicate code, I've added one to my answer.

Comment: could you please let me know the code where we call listener to query?

Comment: You mean this part of your code? `query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ... }` ?

Comment: yes is it suppose to be after `Query query = mReference
                 .limitToLast(page * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD)
                 .orderByChild("rating");` ???

Comment: It would have to be, otherwise there's no query to listen to.

Comment: but how i can get a snapshot which returns after query been made?

Comment: The snapshot is the value that is passed to the `onDataChange` method of the `ValueEventListener`.  You're asking a large number of questions in sequence.  If you have additional questions (beyond the 3 answered above), it probably makes sense to ask new, specific, stackoverflow questions rather than  continue an extended comments discussion.

Comment: hmm... im sorry if it looks like that... but im just trying to clarify answer you gave. to get the whole picture not you provided some info but one part is absent thats why im asking