# 413 Client Error: Request Entity Too Large

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

I want to export big data from firebase real time database. Here is my code:

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('my database link' , None)
Dataset = firebase.get('my database' , '')
```

But I got this error:

```
413 Client Error: Request Entity Too Large for url: 'my database link'
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is suggesting that you have too much data in your Realtime Database to transfer with a single request.  You will have to do something to break it up into multiple requests.  For example, you could request each top-level node separately.  If one of those is too big, you could also use [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711220/firebase-android-pagination) to cycle through the children with multiple requests.

Comment: I'll try it! Thank you so much