# Firebase realtime database paging data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-paging

How can i load data from firebase realtime database starting at X position and ending at Y position for each page so that the next can load from the previous endposition to a new one

basically how to use Paging 3 library by Google here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview

I know the question is not much to go on, but i can't seem to find a way to link the 2 things together

Comment: Pagination in Firebase is based on knowing a specific item, and not on offsets. The topic of [pagination in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+pagination) has been covered *a lot* already, so I recommend reading those, coming up with your own try at a solution, and posting back with a more concrete approach.

Comment: the answer provided in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711220/firebase-android-pagination is helpful for having a small list with "next/back" keys to handle the pagination itself, can't seem to find any solution that uses an endless recyclerview