# Firebase Realtime Database limits

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a large e-commerce app. Here is the node and child number I want to use. I want to make 500 nodes, each node has 1000 child and each child has 10 children like name, price, type, location, phone number, description, date, etc. And my app has daily users are 1000.
Can I use the Realtime Database for this? Users can show data without problems?

Answer (score 1):

None of these sound like they go beyond the documented [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits) of Firebase's Realtime Database.

As usual with NoSQL database, performance will depend more on how you implement things than on the database itself though, so be sure to read the documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), [how to secure data access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) and watch David's classic video series on [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Answer (score 0):

if your data is large then we using paging in our recycler view. we integrate paging in real time to fast your application response. Real time support start position and also limit same as sql.

check this link:

[Firebase android pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711220/firebase-android-pagination)