# Preventing firebase Out of memory exception

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, out-of-memory, sharding

Aside from sharding your real-time database & setting `largeHeap:true` on the Manifest file, how else do you prevent an Out of memory exception on the client-side.

Assume you have 100k+ users in your *customers* node & for each user in order to retrieve their data, you have something like:

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference("customers")
                .child(userId) //The culprit causing the error, since it has to read the entire node 
                .get()
```

How would you tackle this issue?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198293/java-lang-runtimeexception-firebase-database-encountered-an-outofmemoryerror/73203134#73203134) out.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo, I already checked it out, I'm not displaying onto a list, also I checked out your profile & the firebase courses you offer, do you offer firebase consultation or an email perhaps one can reach you, this has been quite a challenge (scaling)